# Swing program exits immediately after starting

Tags: java, swing

The program will launch but then immediately quit. Also, I'm not quite sure if adding multiple panels to a class that extends JFrame is allowed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TravelExpensesCaskey extends JFrame
{
    private double tripDays;
    private double airfareCost;
    private double carRentalFees;
    private double numMiles;
    private double parkingFees;
    private double taxiCharges;
    private double registrationFees;
    private double lodgingCost;

    private final double FOOD_$_PER_DAY = 37.00;
    private final double PARKING_$_PER_DAY = 10.00;
    private final double TAXI_$_PER_DAY = 20.00;
    private final double LODGING_$_PER_DAY = 95.00;
    private final double $_PER_MILE = 0.27;

    private JPanel inputPanel;
    private JPanel messageBar;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel calculateBar;
    private JButton calcButton;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 200;

    private JTextField field2;
    private JTextField field3;
    private JTextField field4;
    private JTextField field5;
    private JTextField field6;
    private JTextField field7;
    private JTextField field8;
    private JTextField field9;

    private double totalExpenditures;
    private double totalAllowance;
    private double totalBalance;
    private double totalStipend;

    public TravelExpensesCaskey()
    {
        setTitle("Travel Expenses");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Please input the following information about your trip. Enter 0 for any irrelavent values.");
        messageBar = new JPanel();
        messageBar.add(label1);
        add(messageBar);

        inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,2));
        inputPanel = buildPanel();
        add(inputPanel);

        calculateBar = buildCalculateBar();
        add(calculateBar);

        setVisible(true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total expenses incurred by the business person: " + totalExpenditures + "." +
                "\nThe total allowance for the business person: " + totalAllowance + "." +
                "\nThe total balance that must be paid for by the business person: " + totalBalance + "." +
                "\nThe total stipend available to the business person: " + totalStipend + ".");

    }

    private JPanel buildPanel()
    {
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Number of Days: ");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Airfare Charges: :");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Car Rental Fees: ");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Number of Miles Driven: ");
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Amount of Parking Fees: ");
        JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Amount of Taxi Charges: ");
        JLabel label8 = new JLabel("Conference/Seminar Registration Fees: ");
        JLabel label9 = new JLabel("Lodging Charges per Night: ");

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel7 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel8 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel9 = new JPanel();

        panel2.add(label2);
        panel3.add(label3);
        panel4.add(label4);
        panel5.add(label5);
        panel6.add(label6);
        panel7.add(label7);
        panel8.add(label8);
        panel9.add(label9);

        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field5 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field6 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field7 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field8 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field9 = new JTextField(10);

        panel.add(panel2);
        panel.add(field2);
        panel.add(panel3);
        panel.add(field3);
        panel.add(panel4);
        panel.add(field4);
        panel.add(panel5);
        panel.add(field5);      
        panel.add(panel6);
        panel.add(field6);
        panel.add(panel7);
        panel.add(field7);
        panel.add(panel8);
        panel.add(field8);
        panel.add(panel9);
        panel.add(field9);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel buildCalculateBar()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(calcButton);
        return panel;
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String userText = "";

            userText = field2.getText();
            tripDays = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field3.getText();
            airfareCost = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field4.getText();
            carRentalFees = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field5.getText();
            numMiles = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field6.getText();
            parkingFees = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field7.getText();
            taxiCharges = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field8.getText();
            registrationFees = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            userText = field9.getText();
            lodgingCost = Integer.parseInt(userText);

            calcCharges();
        }
    }

    private void calcCharges()
    {
        totalExpenditures = (tripDays * lodgingCost) + parkingFees + airfareCost + carRentalFees + taxiCharges + registrationFees;

        totalAllowance = (tripDays * FOOD_$_PER_DAY) + (tripDays + PARKING_$_PER_DAY) + (tripDays * TAXI_$_PER_DAY) 
                            + (tripDays * LODGING_$_PER_DAY) + (numMiles * $_PER_MILE);

        if ((totalExpenditures - totalAllowance) < 0)
        {
            totalStipend = Math.abs(totalExpenditures - totalAllowance);
            totalBalance = 0;
        }
        else if ((totalExpenditures - totalAllowance) > 0)
        {
            totalBalance = totalExpenditures - totalAllowance;
            totalStipend = 0;
        }           
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TravelExpensesCaskey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any output on the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program throw multiple `NullPointerExceptions`. You declare many objects as class fields and then never initialize them. You need to add at least:

- `inputPanel = new JPanel();` in constructor,
- `panel = new JPanel();` in buildPanel();

and in case of all yours `JTextFields`, change from:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
```

to:

```
field = new JTextField();
```

But it is only beginning because you GUI doesn't display most of components. You need to choose `LayoutManager`, and work with it. You add all your panels to center of your frames `BorderLayout` and I think they overlap . So for example, to see your `JTextFields`, `JLabel` and `JButton`, you can change `add(component);` in constructor for:

```
    add(BorderLayout.NORTH, messageBar);
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, inputPanel);
    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,calculateBar);
```

also add:

```
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

in `buildPanel()` method, and it will look better. 
Whats more, you need to move code for JOptionPane to the end of calcCharges() method, this way it will have access to processed date and it will display proper output. At beginning of a app, it displays only zeros.

Comment: Thank you so much! All of your suggested changes were correct and my program works great now. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @HunterCaskey if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. But ofcourse there is no obligation to do this.